# maven build gets terminated while copying web app resources without any error

Tags: java, spring, maven-3

I am trying to do maven build with clean install.. everything goes fine but at the end while copying web app resources to create a war.. build gets terminated without errors. any suggestions please.

terminated snap

terminated snap two

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wyf6L.png)

EDIT: This is my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.mg.mc</groupId>
        <artifactId>Management-core</artifactId>
        <version>${releaseVersion}</version>
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.mg.mc</groupId>
    <artifactId>ManagementServices</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>ManagementServices</name>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mg.mc</groupId>
            <artifactId>ManagementExternalJaxb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mg.mc</groupId>
            <artifactId>ManagementJaxb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mg.mc</groupId>
            <artifactId>ManagementServiceApi</artifactId>
            <type>ejb</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <defaultGoal>install</defaultGoal>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>unpack</id>
                        <phase>process-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>unpack</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>com.mg.mc</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>ManagementServices</artifactId>
                                    <version>${ManagementServices.customer.version}</version>
                                    <type>war</type>
                                    <overWrite>true</overWrite>
                                    <outputDirectory>target/${releaseVersion}/war/</outputDirectory>
                                    <excludes>**/EnterpriseSharedResources*.jar, */EnterpriseInboundListeners.jar</excludes>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <warSourceDirectory>target/${releaseVersion}/war/</warSourceDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: You'll need to share your pom.xml in order for us to help you

Comment: allkenang: thanks for prompt response please find pom.xml below

Comment: <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

 <parent>
  <groupId>com.mg.mc</groupId>
  <artifactId>Management-core</artifactId>
  <version>${releaseVersion}</version>
 </parent>

 <groupId>com.mg.mc</groupId>
 <artifactId>ManagementServices</artifactId>
 <packaging>war</packaging>
 <name>ManagementServices</name>

Comment: <dependencies>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>com.mg.mc</groupId>
   <artifactId>ManagementExternalJaxb</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>com.mg.mc</groupId>
   <artifactId>ManagementJaxb</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>com.mg.mc</groupId>
   <artifactId>ManagementServiceApi</artifactId>
   <type>ejb</type>
  </dependency> 
 </dependencies>

Comment: <build>
  <defaultGoal>install</defaultGoal>
  <plugins>
   <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3</version>
    <executions>
     <execution>
      <id>unpack</id>
      <phase>process-resources</phase>
      <goals>
       <goal>unpack</goal>
      </goals>

Comment: <configuration>
       <artifactItems>
        <artifactItem>
         <groupId>com.mg.mc</groupId>
         <artifactId>ManagementServices</artifactId>
         <version>${ManagementServices.customer.version}</version>
         <type>war</type>
         <overWrite>true</overWrite>
         <outputDirectory>target/${releaseVersion}/war/</outputDirectory>         
         <excludes>**/EnterpriseSharedResources*.jar,
          **/EnterpriseInboundListeners*.jar
         </excludes>         
        </artifactItem>        
       </artifactItems>
      </configuration>

Comment: </execution>
    </executions>
   </plugin>
   <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.1</version>    
    <configuration>
     <warSourceDirectory>target/${releaseVersion}/war/</warSourceDirectory>     
    </configuration>
   </plugin>
  </plugins>
 </build>
</project>

Comment: @allkenang: kindly concatenate above pom.xml file since it is not allowed me to copy and paste in one stretch... Thanks

Comment: You can edit your own question tho @bvr. I did it for you this time

Comment: Thanks for your help.. will make sure for next time @L_Cleo

Comment: can you also add the full output of the maven build (instead of a cropped image)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the documentation, the `unpack` goal of the `maven-dependency-plugin` plugin binds by default to the `process-sources` phase.

So could you change (or just remove) the `<phase>process-resources</phase>` from the plugin configuration